# MVVM-How to Binding ObservableCollection of Strings into ListBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

Normally I bind ObservableCollection to my own classes. But in this case I need to bind ObservableCollection of Strings in ListBox using MVVM into WPF.

My xml is

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxDynamic.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ListBoxDynamic.ViewModel">
<Grid Margin="0,0,-8,0">
    <ListBox Width="100" Height="90"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton Command="{Binding SelectItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Item}" >
                    <ToggleButton.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Item" Text="{Binding What I must to write?}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ToggleButton.Template>
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

My MainViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _listOfItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> ListOfItems
    {
        get { return _listOfItems; }
        set { _listOfItems = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ListOfItems"); }
    }

    public ICommand SelectItemCommand { get; private set; }
    int counter = 1;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ListOfItems.Add("Add new Item");
        SelectItemCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((x) => ExecuteSelectItemCommand(x));

    }
```

But I don't know that I must to write in Binding TextBlock into ToggleButton.

Comment: Wrap the string as a property of a class?

Comment: I don't want do it, Isn't possible only string? 
I don't want create a new class only for binding a property.

Comment: Just write `<TextBlock x:Name="Item" Text="{Binding }" />`

Comment: I tried this nit , but ("Add New Item") element, it doesn't appear.

Comment: @ncampuzano I tried this..working just fine.. are you sure you have set the right datacontext for your view? can you check for any binding errors.

Comment: All code are above... I don't see the DataContext is bad. You see any error?

Comment: @ncampuzano code does not show how are you setting the DataContext of your window

Comment: @nit I'm stupid... So far I noticed

Comment: this is the most common mistake that has made every wpf developer want to kick himself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since data which back each `ListBoxItem` is string, hence `DataContext` of each `ListBoxItem` will be string.

Hence doing `<TextBlock x:Name="Item" Text="{Binding }" />` will show you the string backing the listboxitem in the textblock

Comment: Hi, @nit i have some similar issue seeking some assistance

Comment: where?, here it self?

Answer (score 1):

there are few issues I notices

- the command is available in the view model instead of the data item, so use relative source to bind to command
- "{Binding}" can be used to refer to current Item, so no need to use elementname syntax
- then instead of placing a textbox inside toggle button you can make use of content presenter to make it more flexible

so this could go like this

```
<ListBox Width="100"
         Height="90"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ToggleButton Command="{Binding SelectItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                          Content="{Binding}">
                <ToggleButton.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ToggleButton.Template>
            </ToggleButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: But... The first element that I added, does not appear when I run my app.

Comment: that may not be the issue with the template, try to check the collection if there is the value, also see if there is any binding error in output window.

Comment: Great find @ncampuzano, hoping this template work for you, this is flexible enough to accommodate any type of content providing a toggle behavior, eg image button, drawing button etc.